# C# * and & operaor for pointing to array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, translate, crc16

I am translating a C++ CRC function to C# and I am having problems with passing an a pointer to an (unsigned char) byte array in the function argument. In the C++ sample below

```
unsigned int CRC16_Calculation(unsigned char *buf, unsigned int len){
  unsigned int ix;
  unsigned int index;
  unsigned int crc = 0;

  for(ix=0; ix<len; ix++)
  {
    index = (high ^ buf[ix]) & 0x00FF;  
    crc = (low * 256) ^ Crc16Tbl[index];
  }
  return crc;}
```

I was able to translate this function to C#.

```
    public static unsafe ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] buffer, ushort len)
{
    ushort index;
    ushort crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        index = (ushort)((low ^ buffer[i]) & 0x00FF);
        crc = (ushort)((high * 256) ^ table[index]);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

I need to use the function in C++ as follows:

```
crc= CRC16_Calculation(&Array[3], sizeof(Array)-3);
```

But in C# in gives me an compiler error.

```
ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(Array[3], (ushort)(Array.Length-3));
```

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]*' to 'byte[]'.

The best overloaded method match for 'Program.ComputeChecksum(byte[], ushort)' has some invalid arguments

Is the problem that the C++ function uses a ponter to the unsigned char array and this is not possible with C#, repective only when usinf unsafe?

Comment: You say "I need to use the function in C++ as follows ... but in C# it gives me".  Is the problem how to convert the *call* to the function?  Can you show us a minimal example of the call?

Comment: Does it have to be unsafe? If not: Do not "translate". Write down what it does, then implement it the "C# way". Translations like this hardly ever lead to reasonable code (from my experience).

Comment: You might find the easiest solution is add an additional `ushort offset` argument to the C#, and start the CRC at that offset from the start of the array.

Comment: I added the C# function call which gives the error. This only happens when using Array[3]. Adding Array will work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in C# it's enough to pass only array to a method without its length since `Array` class contains `Length` property in it. So you can rewrite you method to following (`unsafe` is not required since you are not working with pointer in C# code)

```
public static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] buffer)
{
    ushort index;
    ushort crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; ++i) //using Length property
    {
        index = (ushort)((low ^ buffer[i]) & 0x00FF);
        crc = (ushort)((high * 256) ^ table[index]);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

And there are few solutions for you problem. First one is using `Linq`. You can call your method like this

```
ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(arr.Skip(3).ToArray());
```

To use `Skip` method you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Second solution is using `Span`. It requires Visual Studio 2017 (or 2015 with updated compiler), at least .NET framework 4.5 and adding `System.Memory` package using Nuget package manager.

```
var span = new Span<byte>(arr, 3, arr.Length - 3);
ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(span.ToArray());
```

And the most straight forward solution is adding `offset` and `length` paratemers to your method

```
public static ushort ComputeChecksum(byte[] buffer, int length, int offset)
{
    ushort index;
    ushort crc = 0;
    for (int i = offset; i < length; ++i)
    {
        index = (ushort)((low ^ buffer[i]) & 0x00FF);
        crc = (ushort)((high * 256) ^ table[index]);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

and usage

```
int offset = 3;
ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(arr, arr.Length - offset, offset);
```